# I want to solve this problem in PL/SQL the EXCEPTION command does not work

Tags: oracle, plsql

I hope you are fine. I am facing a problem. I dont know why it coming to me, although I think that the code is complete and there are no problems. You will find the code and the error below.

**THE CODE**

```
DECLARE
v_jobid EMPLOYEES.job_id%TYPE;

BEGIN
SELECT job_id INTO v_jobid
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE department_id = 80;

EXCEPTION
WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR1');
END;
```

**THE ERROR**

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PLS-00201: identifier 'EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 6:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

1. DECLARE
2. v_jobid EMPLOYEES.job_id%TYPE;
3. BEGIN
4. SELECT job_id INTO v_jobid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you have now:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2  v_jobid EMPLOYEES.job_id%TYPE;
  3
  4  BEGIN
  5  SELECT job_id INTO v_jobid
  6  FROM EMPLOYEES
  7  WHERE department_id = 80;
  8
  9  EXCEPTION
 10  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
 11  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR1');
 12  END;
 13  /
v_jobid EMPLOYEES.job_id%TYPE;
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PLS-00201: identifier 'EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 6:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Aha. Table or view doesn't exist:

```
SQL> desc employees;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object employees does not exist
```

Let's create it (with only necessary columns for your code to work):

```
SQL> create table employees (job_id number, department_id number);

Table created.
```

Any improvement?

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2  v_jobid EMPLOYEES.job_id%TYPE;
  3
  4  BEGIN
  5  SELECT job_id INTO v_jobid
  6  FROM EMPLOYEES
  7  WHERE department_id = 80;
  8
  9  EXCEPTION
 10  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
 11  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR1');
 12  END;
 13  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 5


SQL>
```

Yes, that's better. Though, it now raised error you didn't handle (`no_data_found`).

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2  v_jobid EMPLOYEES.job_id%TYPE;
  3
  4  BEGIN
  5  SELECT job_id INTO v_jobid
  6  FROM EMPLOYEES
  7  WHERE department_id = 80;
  8
  9  EXCEPTION
 10  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
 11  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR1');
 12
 13  when no_data_found then
 14  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR2');
 15  END;
 16  /
ERROR2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Now code looks OK.

Comment: But I'm writing the code on oracle SQL COMMANDER, I think the table should exist automatically, right?

Comment: Wrong. Why would *anything* exist automatically. BTW, what is "SQL COMMANDER"?

Comment: There is a program called Database 10g Express Edition, when you install it, it gives you permission to access SQL COMMANDER, which is the LOCAL HOST site. Look for it and you will understand me well

Comment: Are you sure? "SQL COMMANDER"? Is it not, by any chance, "SQL Command Line"? 10gXE is an old piece of software, I don't have it so I can't check. Nonetheless, problem you had is related to a non-existent table, whichever tool you might be using.

Comment: Even if such a thing existed, there is clearly not enough information to be scraped from your pl/sql code to create a table with the appropriate definition automatically - what data type should job_id be? What should the primary key be? What other columns should exist and why would it know? If the table needs to exist then you or another person need to create it.